# What or who Ben Ish Hai means with נ"א?

Tags: acronyms

בס"ד

In his derashot[ ([parashah Shoftim, 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Drashot%2C_Shoftim.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) the Ben Ish Hai writes: "פירש הרב נ"א ז"ל".Who is this rabbi נ"א? He cites this acrostic in other places too, but in anyone said the entire name of this rabbi. I don't think was Noam Elimelech. Maybe נ"א is roshei tevot of a name, or maybe is roshei tevot of a title (exemple: נגידי אבי, my nagid my father). I don't know. Can you help me please! Thanks and Kol tuv!

Comment: This is the context:

צדק צדק תרדוף למען תחיה נ"ל בס"ד סמיכות פסוק זה עם הקודם דארז"ל במדרש כל דיין שלוקח שוחד אינו מת מן הזקנה עד שיורה צדק בהוראתו והוא פלאי ופירש הרב נ"א ז"ל דהתנא אמר ולפני מי אתה עתיד ליתן דין וחשבון ופרשו המפרשים דברוב דיני התורה יש פלוגתא דרבוותא הן בתנאים הן באמוראים הן בפוסקים ואלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים רק סוגייא דעלמא אזיל בתר חד מנייהו

Comment: Maybe Rav Nosson Adler?

Comment: In the context of the subject of your quote, which is discussing the resolution of varying viewpoints in halacha, I wonder if the abbreviation could be referencing a the position of the author of Nishmat Adam.

Comment: He would have called him chayai odom

Comment: תודה רבה לכולם. Rav Nosson Adler is improbably. I've search in his book (https://www.hebrewbooks.org/22433) and not found the matters quoted from Ben Ish Hai. I'll begin to search into  Nishmat Adam! Keep in touch.

Comment: Maybe this is ופירוש הרב ניסח אחר זה לשונו

Comment: Just by probability is likely is a sephardic Rav.

Comment: @Gershom Gold: you think like me!  What you said is the first thing I thinked! But HaRav who is? I'm a fanatic of source's check. Emet is the main thing for me. תודה רבה.

Comment: There is a sefer called Nachal Eisan written in a style of drush. I haven't found it online though to see if it fits.